# how to find key from value array jquery. here i want to see the console.log(position). but its shows undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, trie

[image]
If I `console.log(position)` it shows me undefined.

How do I solved it for getting the values. Here I want to make the nodes as a trie in console. output is okay, but if I `console.log(position)` it shows me undefined.

Can any one please help me?

```
var nodes = ["maria","mary","marks"];    
function insert_word(split_nodes) {        
    var rest = [];          
    for ( var i = 0; i<split_nodes.length; i++ ) {
        //console.log(current);
        var word = split_nodes[i];
        var letters = word.split(""); 
        var current = rest;
        //console.log(current);

        for ( var j = 0; j < letters.length; j++ ) {    
            var character = letters[j];
            // console.log(chaaracter);
            var position  = current[ character ];               
            console.log(position);              
            if ( position == null ) {
                current = current[ character ] = j == letters.length - 1 ? 0 : {};
                // console.log(current);
            } else {
                current = current[ character ];
                // console.log(current);
            }
        }
    }
}
insert_word(nodes);
```

this is my output.

Comment: what is the value to split_nodes?

Comment: insert_word(nodes);

split_nodes = ["maria","mary","marks"]  
can you help me to solved it?
thank you

Comment: yes..because current is empty array and you are trying to get object from that..that is the reason

Comment: @ sanatsathyan

how could i solved this? please can you help me?

Comment: What are you trying to output/do from ["maria","mary","marks"]?

Comment: please also add the console result you get in each console

Comment: What are you doing here?? current = current[ character ] = j == letters.length - 1 ? 0 : {};
This seems wrong.

Comment: yes what exactly is you want.
because there are a bunch of in-built methods to get  what you want instead of writing code from scratch for it

Comment: If I am right change `var current = rest;` into `var current = letters;`

Comment: i just to console it as a tree in console. i shouldn't use built in function. so i have to code like this. :(

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You need to show us input and an _*expected output*_. Unless we know expected output, we can't really help you.

Comment: Milan Chheda 
please can you look up. i added a screen shot, it will help you to understand the output of my code. i want it from this.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, All You need is to find the index of element in array.
and here is how you do it.

```
var nodes = ["maria","mary","marks"];
insert_word(nodes);

function insert_word(split_nodes) {
var position = split_nodes.indexOf("Apple");
// insert into array logic 
}
```

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Comment: how could i fix this? can you help me to solve this? i added a screenshot at the top. it would be my output from this code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve with this code, since it doesn't really make sense but I can tell you why it's printing `undefined`:

At `var current = rest;` you are basically calling `var current = []` and afterwards when you call `var position = current[ character ];` you are trying to receive a index that doesn't exists in the `current` variable since your `current`equals and empty array.

---

**Edit 02:**

> @ zeropublix i have to achieve this. if its nonsense than nonsense , but i have to do this. its like trie structure. can you help me to solve the code for me to do so

Solution for your task:

```
var nodes = ["maria","mary","marks"];

function nodesToTree(nodes) {
    var tree = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var word = nodes[i];
        var letters = word.split("");
        var current = tree;

        for (var j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
            var char = letters[j];

            if (Object.keys(current).length <= 0) {
                current[char] = {};
            } else if (!Object.keys(current).includes(char)) {
                current[char] = {};
            }

            if (j+1 == letters.length) {
                current[char] = 0;
            }

            current = current[char];
        }
    }

    return tree;
}



console.log(
    nodesToTree(nodes)
);
```

Comment: how could i fix this? can you help me to solve this? i added a screenshot at the top. it would be my output from this code. 
thanks

Comment: I've expanded my answer (see Edit01). Hope this helps you.

Comment: @ zeropublix
thanks for your suggestion. i can't fix this. can you help me to optimize this code? i added screenshot what i want to. 
Thanks for your cooperation bro

Comment: @imraihan do you mean the console output screenshot? If thats what you want to achieve you are trying to achieve nonsense.

Comment: @ zeropublix  i have to achieve this. if its nonsense than nonsense , but i have to do this. its like trie structure. can you help me to solve the code for me to do so.

Comment: @imraihan since i was looking for a "challenge" anyway : here is the solution (Edit02).

Comment: @imraihan did that answer your question?

Comment: yeah buddy. thanks a lot. but you changes the code a lot :D

Comment: @imraihan i rarely use the code provided to give a full solution. Most of the time i can't work on the basis of that code. But you can take my code to change yours to be complete and correct.